# QT/QML Singleton Undefined Reference

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML file that contains some reusable application-wide data:

**CApplicationData.qml:**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.6
/**
 *  Singleton object to store all application data to be shared between different .qml files.
 *  These objects are received from the cloud or they can be application specific global data.
 */
QtObject {
  ...
  property var userObject

}
```

I've defined `qmldir` file like so:

**qmldir**

```
singleton ApplicationData 1.0 CApplicationData.qml
```

And imported it in each of the QML files where I want to reference it like so:

**CUserEditView.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import "." // QTBUG-34418, singletons require explicit import to load qmldir file

Component.onCompleted {
    Console.log('ApplicationData: '+ApplicationData.userObject)
}
```

This works fine (most places), and when I debug on my development machine, QtCreator, I can see values defined inside of **UserView.qml**, after I display it (as a modal):

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("CUserEditView.qml");
var obj = component.createObject(rootWindow, {});
```

However, when I compile and use `qtwindeploy`, I have discovered that when I attempt to dereference `ApplicationData.userObject`, `ApplicationData.userObject` is undefined inside `CUserEditView` undefined?

Any ideas?

Comment: You have your QML in *qrc* or in a *dir*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was kind of strange behavior but I ultimately figured it out (Undocumented so far as I can tell)

I had to create a new QML sub-directory:

**qml.qrc/applicationdata:**

`/applicationdata/CApplicationData.qml
/applicationdata/qmldir`

with the contents of `qmldir` set to:

`singleton ApplicationData 1.0 CApplicationData.qml`

And add both files to my `qml.qrc`

This also required me to update my references in other `.qml` files to:

`import "qrc:/applicationdata/."`

Comment: This really helps! Save my day! Thank you